# How do I boot windows from an USB without BIOS settings?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, window, boot, bios

It is asking me for a BIOS password. I do not remember myself setting that password. However, the system is old. I want to replace my Ubuntu main OS with Windows 8.1/10.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose boot device option it depend your laptop type

here for some function button https://www.desertcrystal.com/bootkeys

Comment: He wants to do it without BIOS because he doesn't have the password.

Comment: i think the boot device option is not go to the bios, password only required when i go to bios setup